# MongoDB: Get sorted fields from embedded document

Tags: mongodb

My Mongo schema looks like this:

```
{
    "name":"Meeting Name",
    "description":"Description",
    "uuid":"YPCJaijg",
    "participants":[
        "JLKGZnfFkGvX9DHgz",
        "Rkhs4cu7LzyejcTYa"
    ],
    "log":{
        "1423091932927":"Let's do the 10th then",
        "1423092118662":"Ok, the 10th it is.",
        "1423092165083":"[Selected:20150210]"
    }
}
```

I'll need to load the fields of 'log' (timestamp:message) into a textarea, but since it could potentially grow large, I figured I'd want to sort and limit as part of the query.

What's the right way to approach this? I've tried things like

```
db.meetings.find({uuid:"YPCJaijg"},{'log':1,'_id':0}).sort({"log":-1})
```

...but that's not working.  I've been looking into the aggregation framework, but I can't tell if that's the right direction yet.  I'm also not convinced that this schema is appropriate in the first place.

Comment: It can't grow *that* large: the maximum document size is currently 16 megabytes. So either, just load it and deal with it client side, or change your schema.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a problem with your schema:

- evergrowing documents are bad for mongo. Not only the maximum size can not be bigger then 16mb, the fact that you will always add some new information to the document will cause a lot of moves of the document on file system (when padding will be filled)

You can sort your elements while pushing a new value with [$sort during the update operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/). This way you will have them already sorted during the find. If you want to limit the number of elements in the subdocument, you can just use [$slice projection.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/).

Nonetheless you can do this, if I were you I would rather change the schema to have two collections. One that you currently have (without logs) and another just logs.

Comment: Right, I had initially considered a separate collection for just logs, but wanted to start with something simple.  The meeting logs will never need to come anywhere close to 16mb, so I'm going to stick with this schema for now and do client-side sorting.

Comment: In order to use the $sort update operator, logs would have to be an array of objects (documents), right?

Comment: @VirgilDisgr4ce sorry, I missed that part. It should be an array, not an object.